# Issue in fetching 5 records from a large list with caml query

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, jsom

I am unable to fetch the results from a sharepoint where the list has more 20K records. I have to fetch not more than 10 records.

Here is the exception message I am getting. The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

Comment: Pls add more details, are you getting timeout? Or weird error?

Comment: here is the exception message I am getting.

The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

Comment: Pls edit the question to add/include the exception details instead of commenting..

Comment: updated the question with more info

Answer (score 0):

The following might be helpful:
[CAML Query - Going around the 5000 List Item Threshold](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216562/caml-query-going-around-the-5000-list-item-threshold)

Adding the rowlimit in your CAML Query could be a solution.

Are you using CSOM or JSOM? It is easier to help you if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend how you retrieve the items. I presume you have some kind of query. In order for that query to work you need to have an index against that column that is used in querying.

[This ms support article describes the process](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0)